# Embedded Apache DS with jetty - conflicting slf4j-api versions

Tags: jetty, slf4j, apacheds

Seems like Apache Ds has a dependency on slf4j-api v1.5 while jetty needs slf4j-api v1.6. These versions are not compatible with each other. Anyone else run into same issue?